# Casting types from void*

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

From what I understand, this should work:

```
const char* x = "x";
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Passing x into this function:

```
void myClass::passAsVoid(void* v) {
    std::cout << (const char*)v << std::endl;
}
```

The first example prints "x";

The second example prints "\350\224A";

I want to learn what's going on, and the correct approach to do this!

The actual code:

```
float delay = 1;
std::string txt = "random filler text that is not lorum ipsum";
for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); ++i) {
    const char* x = "x";
    std::cout << x << "code1" << std::endl;
    CCSequence* seq = CCSequence::create(CCDelayTime::create(i*delay),
                                         CCCallFuncND::create( this, callfuncND_selector(OverWorldView::setString), (void*)x ),
                                         NULL);
    this->runAction(seq);
}
```

Callback function:

```
void OverWorldView::setString(void* x) {
    std::cout << (const char*)x << "code2" << std::endl;
    label1->setString( (const char*)x );
}
```

I'm using cocos2dx 2.1.4

Comment: How do you call `passAsVoid`? Something like `passAsVoid("x")`?

Comment: Can I ask *why* you need to do this? In C++, you generally, don't need to do this. I would go as far as to say that unless you're dealing with a C API, the correct approach is to not do this at all.

Comment: An api I'm using only accepts void* types =s

Comment: `std::cout << (const char*)v` should print the string. It only prints the pointer address if you leave out the cast... Are you sure this is your actual code?

Comment: You haven't posted valid code, as for example the `passAsVoid` function lacks a return type. Also if you're doing that, the function should accept a `const void*` parameter and not just `void *`, otherwise it's in fact not possible to call `passAsVoid(x)` from your main. Doing it that way works for me, though it's not something you should need to do in C++.

Comment: @H2CO3
Yes, which is why I'm very confused.

Comment: @Hobbyist [A counter-example](http://ideone.com/iI0ci9)

Comment: @Hobbyist Can you post a code snippet where you actually call `passAsVoid` so we can see the call and the argument? There is nothing wrong semantically with doing `cout << (const char*)v` as H2CO3 says.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with your function. I suggest you put the complete program that doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Please Please avoid `void *` especially in C++. There are a multitude of techniques to avoid they and use the power of C++ being more type safe

Comment: @EdHeal: sometimes it's impossible to avoid.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - In pure C++ I cannot think of anything in my experience that required void pointers. Perhaps enlightened us.

Comment: in Qt index.internalpointer takes void* so you can pass there what you want

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the API you're using. Please give us some more information about what you're doing. Is it Cocos2d? Which platform?

Comment: A wild guess: the Cocos2d version I've found (Cocos2d-X) expects the argument of `callfuncND_selector` to be a function taking **two** arguments: a `CCNode*` and a `void*`.

Comment: @DyP
Yup, that's right it's cocos2dx 2.1.4, I'm trying out the wrapper solution right now but I have to change a few other things too, it might take a while.

Comment: Try `void OverWorldView::setString(CCNode*, void* x) { /*...*/ }`., just this change (no wrapper).

Comment: Be aware that the pointer you pass (`x`) has to point to an object that lives until the function (`OverWorldView::setString`) is actually called (it's a delayed call if I interpret that correctly). In this case, it's a string literal (`x = "x"`), and these live as long as the program does - so that's not your current problem - but if you wrap that literal in a `std::string`, you have to take care of the lifetime. You may want to read [this thread in the Cocos2d-x forums](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/7706), it also covers your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the API correctly.

The documentation [says](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d9/d9f/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_call_func_n_d.html#a84188cc6286a5ee461bdb6c393789b3e) you need to use a `SEL_CallFuncND` type callback, which [receives two arguments](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d9/d1f/group__base__nodes.html#ga6144b3c0fe44743245e139e0b49f0f96), not one.

For everyone's convenience, `callfuncND_selector` [is a macro that hides a static_cast](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d9/d1f/group__base__nodes.html#gaf6e1b4d4334a7aa7950a17f361aaff80), or probably even a C-style cast (could not find other API versions online) which lets you use just about anything as a callback without getting any compilation errors. Pure joy.

Comment: The version the OP is using uses a C-style cast: `#define callfuncND_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_CallFuncND)(&_SELECTOR)` m( The `static_cast` would have catched that error at compile-time (the new version 3.something introduces the `static_cast`).

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far, I've used this exact callbackselector to pass a vector as the only argument before and it worked, I'm not sure why it doesn't this time, this solution seems to work but there's still some error in my code that I have to iron out first!

Comment: "could not find other API versions online" yeah, I downloaded the framework (cocos2d-x 2.1.4) and looked into the code, that's where my quote is from.

Comment: Sorry everyone I actually have to run for now, I'll update this question again once I'm back in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

This won't even compile because you're passing a const pointer to a function which accepts a non-const pointer. If you can't change the type of the callback then instead of passing a string literal, pass a character array.

```
char buffer[100];

callback(buffer); //buffer decays to char* which is implicitly converted to void*
```

If you can change the type of the callback though then modify the parameter to be `const void*`.